# Sequelize TypeScript: How to use `createdAt` in scope's `where` condition if it is not as part of model's attributes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I try to use Sequelize with TypeScript. I copy the code from [official document TypeScript section](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html) like this:

```js
// These are all the attributes in the User model
interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  preferredName: string | null;
}

interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, "id"> {}

class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>
  implements UserAttributes {
  public id!: number; 
  public name!: string;
  public preferredName!: string | null;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

However, when I initialize User table, I want define a default scope, like `updatedAt` filed have to satisfy some conditions:

```js
  User.init(userTableAttributes,
    {
      tableName: "user",
      sequelize,
      paranoid: true,
      defaultScope: {
        where: {
          updatedAt: {
            [Op.eq]: null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

But this code is wrong, it seems the because the `updatedAt` field in not defined in `UserAttributes`.

So how can I solve this problem? I only come up with one way: define the `updatedAt` field in `UserAttributes`? But it doesn't make any sense, because I think the `UserAttributes` only include business attributes, right?

Comment: sequelize will automatically create `createdAt`and `updatedAt` column in your tables if you have seted `define: {
    timestamps: true
  },` in your sequelize.js file

Answer (score 1):

I found out if I added `paranoid`, it will auto add `deletedAt is NULL` condition in query string